# bazel pypi macro self-edge

Tags: pypi, bazel

I'm stumbling around trying to get bazel working with pypi dependencies.

./pypi.bzl:

```
def _impl(ctx):
  ctx.actions.run_shell(
    command = "pip download %s" % ctx.package
  )

_pypi_package = rule(
  implementation=_impl,
  attrs={"package": attr.label(mandatory=True)},
)

def pypi_package(package):
  _pypi_package(name = package, package = package)
```

./BUILD:

```
py_binary(
  name = "app",
  srcs = ["app.py"],
  deps = [":python-dateutil"]
)

load("//:pypi.bzl", "pypi_package")

pypi_package(
  package="python-dateutil",
)
```

Trying to build:

```
$ bazel build app
ERROR: /path/to/cwd/BUILD:9:1: in _pypi_package rule //:python-dateutil: cycle in dependency graph:
    //:app
.-> //:python-dateutil [self-edge]
`--
This cycle occurred because of a configuration option.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:app' failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.219s
```

No idea if this is even the right approach for working with external dependencies, but ignoring that, I don't understand where the self-dep here is coming from. In fact, I don't see that I'm declaring any deps for the `pypi_package` rule at all. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was `attr.label`: "label" here means BUILD label. I should have been using `attr.string`.

Comment: I think you also need to specify `outputs` for [`run_shell`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#run_shell), otherwise Bazel has no reason to run the action (since nothing depends on its outputs).